# Why cURL does not return error on invalid URLs?

Tags: php, url, curl, error-handling

I want to use cURL in my PHP application. I went to [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and found its documentations. But when I wanted to implement my codes, I found out that cURL does not return error always on invalid URLs.
To make sure about it, I changed the URL mentioned in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to `http://www.googles123.com` that is not valid and registered.

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle to a non-existing location
$ch = curl_init('http://www.googles123.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The result was **Operation completed without any errors**! Whereas this code returned error on its default URL `http://404.php.net/`. Why?

Comment: You have to use curl_getinfo($ch) and check the error_code of html. Also all errors are in curl_errno($ch).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.googles123.com/");

// Send request
curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}

// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Curl error message : Couldn't resolve host name

Can you try above code?

Comment: it's works. please check above code in individual file.

Can you tell me which server are you using like Wamp/Xampp?

Comment: It's really strange. Now both your and mine codes are working! I am using XAMPP. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set CURLOPT_FAILONERROR to false

```
**curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FAILONERROR , false);**
```